# Chess Pieces like classic 1997 "Pure Mate" ad

Tags: chessboards

I used to have this print up on my locker in highschool, and have had a blown-up, framed version in my living room for the past several years.

I've recently started playing chess regularly again and was looking to buy a new board, and was wondering if anyone could recommend a place to purchase a similarly detailed set.

The ad is titled "Pure Mate" from 1997.  I'm not sure if I'm allowed to link amazon or an outside site in these posts, but this if so here is the ad in question:  [http://www.amazon.com/Smirnoff-Vodka-Bottle-Chess-Pieces/dp/B00764VM14](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00764VM14)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these themed sets from House of Staunton.  I don't see the set you're looking for, but you can expect whatever they have to be very high quality.  I love the Isle of Lewis set.

http://www.houseofstaunton.com/chess-pieces/themed-chess-pieces.html?src=feature